# LaTex Text Justification badness penalty

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I had been going through dynamic programming concepts and happened to read about text justification problem in which the spaces to the right of the line end are penalized with cubic times the number of spaces. The algorithm also works with [quadratic times](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/word-wrap-problem-dp-19/) number of spaces as penalty. I have couple of questions 1) Any idea why this works with both cubic & quadratic? 2) Why it should be cubic or quadratic why not just linear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optimization function is designed in a way to find a solution that:

- uses a small number of lines
- is balanced (the number of extra spaces at the end of each line should be about the same length)

---

Lets look first at the linear optimization function, i.e. the sum of all extra spaces.

It is very clear, that the optimal solution under that function is one that uses the minimum number of lines.
However it will not fulfill the second goal.
The number of extra spaces is equal in each solution that uses the same number of lines.

For instance if you want to split the string `a.bb.ccc` at line-width 6.
The unbalanced solution

```
a.....
bb.ccc
```

has the same penalty 5 (number of extra spaces) as the balanced solution

```
a.bb..
ccc...
```

. So if you only optimize with a linear function, then you might end up with an unbalanced solution.

---

Now lets look at the the sum of squares.

The intuition is, that having lines with a lot of extra spaces will get penalized a lot more than lines with less extra spaces.

Using the same example. The unbalanced solution

```
a.....
bb.ccc
```

will get a bigger penalty $5^2 + 0^2 = 25$ than

```
a.bb..
ccc...
```

which has only a penalty of $2^2 + 3^2 = 13$.

You can actually partially prove that this will give us a balanced solution.

If you fixate the number of lines, than also the number of necessary extra spaces is fixed. Let's assume than we need $n$ lines with $m$ extra spaces. I'll denote $a_i$ for the number of extra spaces in line $i$.

We want to optimize $$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^2$$
We know (using the QM-AM inequality), that

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^2 \ge \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)^2}{n} = \frac{m^2}{n} = \text{const}$$

and that we reach equality for $a_i = \frac{m}{n}$ for all $i$.

So the minimum of the optimization function is reached, when every lines has exactly the same number of extra spaces.

Notice, that usually this is not possible (because of the different word lengths in the string).

But the result supports the argument, that this optimization function ends up with a solution that we human would call "balanced".

---

The cubic function, and many other ones, will work in exactly the same way. Unbalanced solutions will end up with a higher penalty than balanced solutions.

---

Btw, $\LaTeX$ uses the sum of squares as penalty. At least [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap#Minimum_raggedness) claims so.

Comment: Thanks @Jakube. Can you please elaborate a bit on AM-QM inequality stuff or give me a pointer to the theory please? BTW, nice explanation & I accept this as an answer.

Comment: The HM-GM-AM-QM inequalities are a set of inequalities that hold for any set of positive numbers. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities. I've just used the QM-AM part, since QM contains the sum of squares and AM the normal sum (which is fixed in our problem). I've taken that inequality, squared it and mulitplied by n.

Comment: A well known fact is, that the inequality turns into an equality, if all numbers are the same. Since our right side is constant, this constant also acts as the minimum value that is possible (if every line has the same number of extra spaces).